# toolstripbutton with images for each state

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripbutton, onhover

I have in my app a ToolSrip with some ToolStripButtons.
I wish add not only the basic image, but an image for the hover state and another for the clicked state, and if possible, remove the orange background when the button is hovered by the mouse...
it's possible?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the events of the button you can see various events including. This isnt working code its just a sample from my head but look at the link.

```
private void Button1_OnMouseHover
{
   BackGroundImage = "test.png";
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripbutton.aspx